# TOraSession.Connect => Invalid Oracle Home: <nothing>

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Cloud using TOraSession (Newest version).

I have set it up the classic way:

```
  FConnection := TOraSession.Create(nil);
  FTransaction := TOraTransaction.Create(FConnection);
  FTransaction.DefaultSession := FConnection;
  FConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
  FConnection.ConnectString := GetConnectString;
  FConnection.AutoCommit := true;
```

Im sure, I use the correct ConnectionString, since I've tested it in an UDL file. 
But when connection I get an Error message: Invalid Oracle Home: .  I doesn't say `<nothing>` . but just an empty string.

In the environment settings I have setup  ORACLE_HOME  and I've added  %ORACLE_HOME%\bin to the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of the oracle client are you using? 32 bit or 64bit? I assume your application is 32bit?

Comment: It is the 64 bit version and my client is 32 bit

Comment: I believe the Ora client must have the same bitness as your application or it won't work...

Comment: If I compile under 64 bit I get an other error:
Cant initialize OCI. Error -1.

Comment: I would install the 32 bit client if I were you. The OCI Error indicates that OCI.dll can't be found (I assume you windows environment PATH variable is correct?

Comment: I'll do that and return

Comment: No luck now I get the OCi error

Comment: Still seems like a configuration problem now. Using Procmon may give you a clue?

Comment: My knowledge of Oracle is very limited. I have asked an Oracle Pro. When he have solved the problem I'll post a solution in here. Thank you for your help

Comment: Depending on the edition of ODAC available you can do a direct connection and skip Oracle Home and the Oracle client all together (Options : Direct) ref: [TOraSessionOptions.Direct Property](https://www.devart.com/odac/docs/devart.odac.torasessionoptions.direct.htm).